# How to catch a dot in Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I'm trying to execute this lines of code:

```
  my $test = 'test .15oz test';
  $test =~ /([\d]+)([\.]?[\d]+)*oz\b/;
  print("test=$1\n");
```

The output of this is:

```
  test=15
```

I want to catch that dot. What am I doing wrong?
The best would be to catch **0.15** somehow, but for now I can't even get a dot.

Any help with getting 0.15 from `regex` would be appreciated, so:

> 0.15 -> 0.15
>
> .15 -> 0.15
>
> ..15 -> 0.15
>
> 0.0.0.15 -> 0.15
>
> 000.15 -> 0.15
>
> 15 -> 15

I tried also:

```
$test =~ /([\d]+)(\.?[\d]+)*oz\b/;
$test =~ /([\d]+)([.]?[\d]+)*oz\b/;
```

But with no success. Still getting "15".

Comment: You shouldn't escape a dot with a backslash inside a character class. Only outside. So either `\.` or `[.]` (there are other flavors of regexes that might fail when presented with superfluous backslash escapes, so it's best to avoid it). Anyway, that's not the problem here.

Comment: The character classes themselves appear to be superfluous.

Comment: @blubberdiblub thanks for a suggestion, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Use `$test =~ /(\d*\.?\d+)oz\b/;`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah! that worked, thanks! this should be an answer. Btw. I'm not sure why this q was downvoted

Comment: Good, I posted with a bit of an explanation.

Comment: @ikegami You should have read one more line: **EDIT: Sorry, actually it doesn't work here either :( damn..** I edited my question at least 30 min before your comment. But really appreciate the afford, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the first capturing group. In your pattern, `([\d]+)([\.]?[\d]+)*oz\b`, the first capturing group matches one or more digits. To capture the whole float or integer number before `oz`, use

```
$test =~ /(\d*\.?\d+)oz\b/;
          ^         ^
```

where `\d*\.?\d+` will match 0+ digits, an optional dot (note it is escaped outside a character class) and 1+ digits.

Answer (score 4):

The strings you want to match are matched by

```
(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)oz
```

(Wiktor Stribiżew posted something shorter, but far less efficient.)

So you want

```
if ( my ($match) = $test =~ /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)oz/ ) {
   say $match;
}
```

---

You can't possibly match `0.15` if your input `.15` or `..15`. Simply fix up the string independently of the match.

```
$match = "0".$match if $match =~ /^\./;
```

Similarly, trimming leading zeros is best done outside of the match.

```
$match =~ s/^0+(?!\.)//;
```

---

All together, we get

```
if ( my ($match) = $test =~ /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)oz/ ) {
   $match =~ s/^0+(?!\.)//;
   $match = "0".$match if $match =~ /^\./;
   say $match;
}
```